# Why can a process with independent increments never be a stationary process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, independence, stationarity

Why can a process with independent increments never be a stationary process?

I don't understand the reasoning behind this.

Thanks !

Comment: Is this an exercise question? See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info. In any case, note that a process with a constant value is both stationary and has independent increments.

Comment: You probably mean independent increments with non-zero expectation? Any sequence of iid variables is stationary, and have independent increments with zero mean (assuming the mean exists ...)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen If the $X_n$ are iid random variables, then surely the increment $X_{n+1}-X_n$ is not independent of the increment $X_n - X_{n-1}$? Their covariance is $-\operatorname{var}(X_n)$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't supply sufficient conditions so I'll have to make a small assumption: here let all increments have variance $>0$ (this could be broadened slightly)

Let $S_t = X_1+X_2+...+X_t$  (where the $X_i$ are independent but not necessarily identically distributed increments).

Then consider $\text{Var}(S_t)-\text{Var}(S_{t-1})$; in a stationary process it should be $0$ but you should be able to show it isn't.