# Can i say an iid process with $0$ mean has homogeneous independent increment?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, independence, iid

I think the title is itself self-explanatory. My idea says that an IID process with $0$ mean has to have independent increment. But, I do not understand how to prove homogeneity?

Comment: Consider  iid $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ with $X_i \sim Bernoulli(0.5)$.  What is $Pr(X_i - X_{i-1}=1)$?  What is $Pr(X_i - X_{i-1}=1~ \textrm{and}~ X_{i-1} - X_{i-2} = 1)$?  (Or do I misunderstand what you mean by an IID process?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JuhoKokkala! You are correct about the IID process. Maybe I am not clear about the homogeneous process. Should not we check $P(X_i - X_{i-1} = j) = P(X_i - X_{i-1} = j) $ for $i=1,\ldots, n$ and $j=-1,0,1$?

Comment: Did you compute the probabilities I asked for?

Comment: Yes, $P(X_i-X_{i-1} = 1)=1/4$ and $P(X_i - X_{i-1}=1 ~\text{and} ~X_{i-1} - X_{i-2}=1) =0$. What can I conclude from here? Thanks!

Comment: If $P(AB)=0$ and $A$ and $B$ have probability $1/4$, what does that tell you about whether the relationship $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$ holds or not?

Comment: Thanks, @Dilip. The relation does not hold. That I noticed earlier. What I don't understand is why this relates to homogeneity? I learned: A stochastic process is said to be homogeneous in space if the transition probability between any two state values at two given times depends only on the difference between those state values. Am I right?

Comment: Please consider my first comment.

Comment: The point is that an iid process with 0 mean doesn't have to have independent increments, and therefore clearly doesn't have to have homogenous independent increments.

Comment: Can you give a counter-example? I considered the second comment true of this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189366/why-can-a-process-with-independent-increments-never-be-a-stationary-process).

Comment: $Y_i = X_i-0.5$ with $X_i$ defined as in the previously discussed example has zero mean and  exactly the same increments as $X_i$